# Turn off Workbook.Open event and then modify the VBA code. Infinte loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very hard problem with a project that took me a lot of time to create.
I am desperate at the moment.
I know I was a fool, but now it's just time to find a solution.
In the Workbook.Open() I added a line that calls a function. But unfortunately this function has an infinite loop. 
Now i must find a way to open the workbook without running the macro, but then open the VBA code and modify that damn function or least comment that damn line, in order to continue my work. 
Please. Help. I need you. I'll send you a reward if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold Shift while opening your workbook

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be copying the file to another folder, a non-trusted path so VBA won't activate by default when you open it.

Comment: yeah but this way i can not modify the VBA code. If I want to, I must activate the macros, but when I do the Workbook.Open gets started. Thanks anyway